# ES6: .reduce function

Tags: reactjs, jsx, reduce, es6-modules

I'm trying to sum the value of object inside Array.
Here's my array:

```
"seasons":[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Season 1"
    "stocks":[
        {
          "size": "s",
          "stock": "5"
        },
        {
          "size": "m",
          "stock": "5"
        },
        {
          "size": "l",
          "stock": "5"
        }
     ]
   }
], ...
```

Here's where I want to implement it

```
      <tbody>
            {seasons.length ? 
              seasons.map(seasons => (
                <React.Fragment>
                    {seasons.items.length ? 
                        seasons.items.map(season=> (
                            <tr onClick={()=>this.handleClick(season.id)}>
                              <td>{season.stocks.reduce((stock)=>stock, 0)}
                            </tr>
                            ))
                        :
                        <React.Fragment/>
                    }
                </React.Fragment>
              ))
              : 
              <React.Fragment/>
            }
     </tbody>
```

I know .reduce needs at least 2 arguments, but i can't think of any way to do this. I tried mapping it first

```
{season.stocks.length ? season.stock.map(stock=>(
  stock.reduce()
)):<div/>}
```

and of course it fails because once i mapped it, it is no longer an array.
Is there anyway i can sum the value the total of "stock"? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reduce function is missing an accumulator value (which holds the "reduced" value, i.e. the second value you are talking about).

To give you a simpler `reduce` example so you can understand what the accumulator does:

```
const totalOfArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce((total, value) => total += value, 0); //1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
```

The accumulator value is stored in variable `total`. `reduce` iterates over the array and every loop, `value` is added on to `total`.

Now we can translate this to your use case, which is getting the total stock value. I think what you are trying to do here

```
<td>
    { season.stock.reduce((totalStock, stockItem) => totalStock += parseInt(stockItem.stock), 0) }
</td>
```

Notice the `parseInt`, in your data array the `stock` is a string and not a number. If you reduce a string you end up with a concatenated string rather than the total stock number. We can demonstrate this by running a simple test in our browser console:

```
const totalOfArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'].reduce((total, value) => total += value, ''); //12345
```

And that is why you have to do the `parseInt`.

Check out the [documentation on Array#reduce here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)